# VSTS Profiler used to profile a VSTO Word Addin?

Tags: ms-word, profiling, vsto

I've got a VSTO 3.0 Word addin that I'd like to profile using VSTS Profiler.

When I try to run an instrumenting run with the profiler, though, I get a warning that it can't be instrumented because the Addin DLL is signed, which, from what I know about VSTO, they have to be signed.

Is there any way to "turn off" the signature verification on Word VSTO addins?

Barring that, theoretically, I could NOT sign my addin, compile it, instrument it, and then delay sign it at the end of the build process, but I was hoping to avoid those kinds of hijinks with the project files.